# How can show Unicode Han Character 'U+200D0' (U+200D0) in my browser,LXTerminal , mousepad?

Tags: browser, fonts, debian

The appearance Unicode Han Character 'U+200D0' (U+200D0) is as below:

[image]

Show in my browser:

The font setting in my browser is `noto sans cjk sc`:

[image]

It can't be shown in my browser!
[image]

Shown on my LXTerminal(debian10 + lxde + LXTerminal):
The font setting in my LXTerminal is as below:
[image]

```
python3
>>> '\u4f60'
'你'
>>> '\u000200D0'
'\x0200D0'
```

It can't be shown in the LXTerminal either.

Shown with mousepad:
Write it in `/tmp/test.txt` first and open it with mousepad.

```
x="\U000200D0"
fh = open('/tmp/test.txt','wb')
fh.write(x.encode('utf-8'))
4
fh.close()
```

It can't be shown with mousepad either!

[image]

How can set the font for my browser and terminal and mousepad(or os--debian) to make the han character `U+200D0` be shown normally?

I found that it can be shown in my windows10(both in chrome and notepad).

Edit the `test.html`,and open it with chrome in my windows10.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #font1{
        font-family:"宋体";
        }
        #font2{
        font-family:"Noto Sans CJK SC";
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <p id='font1'>
        try with font1 to show --&#131280;
     </p>
    <p id='font2'>
        try with font1 to show --&#131280;
    </p>
</html>
```

[image]

Open it with chrome in my debian10.

[image]

I have copied and installed `Microsot YaHei` font from my windows10 into debian10 this way:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/fonts/msyh
sudo cp directory_contain_microsof_yahei /usr/share/fonts/msyh
sudo chmod 644 /usr/share/fonts/msyh/*
cd /usr/share/fonts/msyh
sudo mkfontscale
sudo mkfontdir
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

All the issue still can't be solved!

Comment: Why would you use Unicode escape codes? Just write  directly? Any unicode-compatible system should be able to deal with that. And of course in the browser: remember to set the correct charset (e.g. utf-8) and use your dev tools to see which font is being applied, and using CSS to force the right font.

Comment: I have never write the string in unicode escape codes,it is written with utf-8 in binary bytes into `test.txt`.

Comment: Except the code you're showing literally uses unicode escape codes instead of just "the text itself". That said, again: if you want text to show up: (1) make sure it's saved with correct encoding, (2) make sure it gets _loaded_ with the correct encoding, and (3) make sure you have a font installed that supports it. Steps 1 and 2 are language/application specific, step 3 is dependent on your OS (except for browsers, which have an additional mechanism available through CSS font face rules).